# DVI won't synch with LG L204WT

Tags: dvi, lg-monitor

I have a LG L204WT which has VGA and DVI connectors. Until recently, I have used the monitor via VGA, but now I have upgraded the graphics board and switched to DVI.

The problem is that each time after the computer starts, the monitor either doesn't show anything (black screen, but doesn't go into standby) or the picture is distorted.

I then switch the monitor off and on several times, and at some point it starts correctly and then I can work as usual. This only happens on startup.

It is one out of 3 monitors, the other two work fine.

It seems to me as if the monitor is not able to synchronize on the DVI signal and either shows a distorted picture or nothing at all.
There are no settings in the monitor setup that would change anything.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only help is to use the VGA-connection.
No way so far to make DVI work.